# How to get number of days ago from a epoch time from current day?

Tags: java, date, time, format, epoch

I have a scenario where epoch time is in string . I need to convert this to number of days ago from current time .

Eg:

```java
String epoch = "1600852773514";
Date expiry = new Date(Long.parseLong(epoch));
```

Expiry gives me Wed Sep 23 14:49:33 IST 2020 .But I want to get number of days from today to the time 'epoch' . Like epoch is 240 days ago from today.

```
If expiry > 30 days
pass
else
fail
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where is it failing? Post your code

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `Instant`,  `LocalDate` and/or other classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: If the expiry is Wed Sep 23 14:49:33 IST 2020 and current time is Sep 24 13:02, do you want to count one day already (since the dates are different), or do you want to count 1 day only after 14:49:33 today?

Comment: As a possibly easier alternative add 30 days to the expiration date and time (use for example `ZonedDateTime.plusDays()`) and compare the result to the current moment.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```java
Date expiry = /* ... */;
Date now = new Date();

long days = (now.getTime() - expiry.getTime()) / 86_400_000;

if (days > 30) /* ... */
```

So we take the difference of the time in milliseconds:

```java
long diff = (now.getTime() - expiry.getTime());
```

If we divide by 86.000.000 (this is how many milliseconds a day has), we get the number of past days.

Comment: This is not correct. While most days are 86 400 000 milliseconds long, not all are.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you could use `java.time` (since Java 8) and count the days between two dates:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // example String
    String epoch = "1618991673000";
    // parse it to a long
    long epochMillis = Long.parseLong(epoch);
    // then create an Instant from that long value
    Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(epochMillis);
    // and convert it to an OffsetDateTime at UTC (+00:00)
    OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneOffset.UTC);
    // get today's date (only, no time of day considered)
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
    // and extract the date of the OffsetDateTime
    LocalDate then = odt.toLocalDate();
    // count the days between the two dates
    long daysGone = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(then, today);
    // and print the result...
    System.out.println("Days between " + then
                        + " and today (" + today + "): " + daysGone);
}
```

This outputs (today, 21st of May 2021):

```
Days between 2021-04-21 and today (2021-05-21): 30
```

Afterwards, you can easily check if the amount of days is greater or less than allowed in your scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Converting to Instance's and using Duration class:

```
String  epoch = "1600852773514";
Instant start = Instant.ofEpochMilli(Long.parseLong(epoch));
Instant now   = Instant.now();
Long    diff  = Duration.between(start,now).toDays();

System.out.println(diff);
```